# Which site to post svn questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which of S[OFU] would be best for SVN questions? My initial thought is SF for the question I have in mind (regarding setting up the server and getting it working), but version control is used nearly exclusively by programmers, so would SO be more appopriate? Am I thinking too much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- SVN command, scripts, usage, best practice - Stack Overflow.
- SVN repository with regard to performances, backups (Used by programmers, but I hope they don't set up the servers themselves) - Server Fault.
- SVN for personal recreation - Super User.

Comment: yep, sounds about right to me. There can be some overlap around the edges and that is OK too.